# Deploy two spring boot applications with shared database into AWS (architecture)

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have two spring boot applications with shared database. Locally everything works perfect, I can run war files (tomcat is embedded) on ports 8080 and 8081.

Question is, how I can run it on AWS?

I know, there are a lot of possibilities, but I am really a beginner and have no experience. I just tried to run it on AWS as it is (as .war files) and open ports... this is working of course. But this is not secure for PROD. Another issue, I cannot serve it as HTTPS.

My imagine is described in the picture. Probably there should be some splitter (marked as ???X1) in the front and some container for the applications (???Y1).

Please, could somebody help me here? What is the best/simplest/the most secure/best performance solution.

Q2: I am not sure, whether I should use embedded tomcats for war applications.

Thank you in advance

[picture of architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfdjB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "splitter" thing in your image would be an Application Load Balancer on AWS. And you can create free SSL certificates in AWS ACM that can be attached to the Application Load Balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Launch your both apps on one Ec2 Instance( WebServer Instance) , use different ports (80,81), Launch this Ec2 instance in Public Subnet.

`Launch another Instance for your Database and keep that instance in Private Subnet`.
this Database instance will be accessed by only Public subnet's Instance ( WebServer Instance)..

keeping Database Instance in Private Subnet will make it secure as no one can access it other than your own webserver.

OR

Use Amazon RDS for your Database, which is managed service and secure one.

Comment: RDS is deprecated I think... and DB I installed manually, operations are done by jpa/hibernate so it is ok I think. Issue is how to make it HTTPS (SSL), there should be maybe some load balancer in front or something like that to route request to correct application. I have no issue with DB connection.

Comment: @jammin197 RDS is not deprecated! Amazon RDS is the correct way to host a database  on AWS. You would still use jpa/hibernate to connect to the RDS server.

Comment: Thank you. Now I do not know, if I should use elastic beanstalk and deploy war1, then war2 (as new second elastic beanstalk). And both of them will connect to third machine (database server). Am I right? Or better to run both applications in one instance and separate the database? Then I must to create load balancer manually.... or use some jboss/docker? I am really lost. :/